# Error: no call back function provided when trying to Get Response Header with Mocha/Express/Node.js

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mocha.js

I am trying to retrieve an object by its ID and test the response header message.  I have come up with a piece of Mocha code (shown below); but, I get an error saying that **no call back function provided**.  I have seen a couple of online examples and cannot find a clue.  Please help.  Thank you.

```
var Mongo = require('mongodb');
var MongoClient = Mongo.MongoClient;
request = require('request');
should = require('should');

describe('GET /ecrud/v1/core/dbq/534e930204dd311822ec1c9d', function() {
    it ('Check header message', function(done) {
        request.get( MongoClient.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/core/dbq/534e930204dd311822ec1c9d'), function(err, response, header) {
            response.Warning.should.equal('100 Max Record Limit Exceeded');
            done();
        } )
    } )
} )
```

Answer (score 0):

According to all of the examples in the [readme](https://github.com/mongodb/node-mongodb-native), a callback is supposed to be passed to MongoClient.connect().

Also, `MongoClient.connect()` does not return anything, so `request.get(undefined, function(...) {})` will be called when that test is ran.